# Point a AAR to itself and not Maven version

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a series of libraries that I am hosting on Artifactory. One library had a recent change introduced where a new method was created.

I have my project setup where my core project holds several other libraries, and there is a configuration change to point to my local version rather for development rather than the Artifactory version.

So... calling the new method in library B works fine from the core library A. But calling the method in library B from another class within its package... fails.

It is trying to load the exploded aar from the cache of the most recent release. This is stopping a build, and ultimately, a product release.

Here's the build.gradle of the library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: '../../gradle/script/dependencies.gradle'

buildscript {
    apply from: '../../gradle/script/buildscript.gradle'
    repositories {
        myMaven()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$ext.gradleBuildToolsVersion"
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.0.0'
    }
}

apply from: "../../gradle/script/buildscript.gradle"
repositories {
    myMaven()
}



def globalConf = rootProject.ext

// Artifactory versions
ext {
    artifactPackageName = "com.foo.library"
    artifactVersion = "5.9.25"
    artifactName = "foo"
    artifactoryRepo = 'android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion globalConf.androidTargetSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion globalConf.androidBuildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion globalConf.androidMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion globalConf.androidTargetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName project.ext.artifactVersion
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }

    compile('com.foo.library:core:5.9.25@aar') { transitive = true }
    compile 'com.internal.dependency.one:i-d-o:5.9.15@aar'
    compile 'com.internal.dependency.two:i-d-t:5.9.15@aar'
}

apply from: '../../gradle/script/artifactory.gradle'
```

What gradle configuration do I need to establish in order to ensure that the Java classes, when they are calling another class/method in it's own package, are pointing to the local development version of that class and not the most recent AAR from Maven  ?

Comment: The question is not clear. What does it mean " in order to point a library to itself" ?

Comment: Sorry, i'll attempt an edit

Answer (score 0):

1. First check whether the right artificatory got published with right version number.
2. Go to your main project and check the dependencies. Make changes to the version to reflect the right artifacts.
3. If you are using Android Studio, you can got to File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart. This should bring your latest artifacts and clean the old ones.
4. You can always go to app->build->intermediates-> exploded-aar->
   Here you will see list of aars.
5. Make sure each library points to right artifactory versions.

Comment: #1 is not the issue... 
#3 I've done
#5 I'm pretty sure is not the issue either